# What does といい mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I don't know if I'm reading it right but there is a sentence a can't understand. I found といい like connecting two nouns and I didn't find any information about it.

> 今日の部会での様子といい正直お前怪しすぎるぞ (manga Beastars)

Comment: One more instance: ショイグ国防相もこれに合わせて演説するといい、ウクライナ軍の反転攻勢でロシア軍が苦戦を強いられる中、国民の「総動員」が宣言されるのではないかという観測がくすぶっている。

Answer (score 9):

This といい is a set expression used to list things. It's usually used twice in a sentence and means something like "with regard to A and also B (and others)".

- [JLPT N1 Grammar といい～といい (to ii~to ii)](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%84-to-ii-to-ii/)
- [Learn JLPT N1 Grammar: といい～といい (to ii~to ii)](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n1-grammar-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%84-to-iito-ii/)
- [Difference between 〜といい〜といい　＆　〜といわず〜といわず](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9811/5010)

In your case, the といい part is working as a reason for saying お前は怪しすぎる. といい is used only once, but it implies there are other reasons.

> 今日の部会での様子といい、正直お前怪しすぎるぞ。
> From the way you were at the meeting, among other reasons, you look so suspicious, to be honest.