# How is といわず used in this sentence?

Tags: sentence, reading-comprehension

> うめえ。　5キロといわず　もっといけたな

The sentence before this has nothing to do with it (the character is eating and not listening to the other character's speech) so he blurts out this.

The only context is that he asked 5 kilos of meat to eat so they made a dinner for him with 5 kilos of meat.

といわず seems to be "Whatever is or not..." but then how does it related to もっといけた? Which seems to be "It's more delicious"?

Comment: This should have been marked as duplicate, see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9811/difference-between-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%84-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%84-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%82%8F%E3%81%9A-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%82%8F%E3%81%9A).

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that a phrase has been suppressed here, since といわず occurs in pairs, usually:

日本語といわず外国語といわずどんな言葉でもそうなんです "It's the same in any language, whether it be Japanese or a foreign language."

先生といわず医者といわず考えはおなじでしょう 'Not only the teacher, but the doctor too thinks the same way, you see.'

So I would imagine the sense here is '[I] could have done with more, not only 5 kg'. This is 話し言葉, so my understanding may be faulty; others will correct me, if so.